# pass a javascript variable from javascript to vuejs component

Tags: vue.js

I have a vue component that needs some data. I easily create and pass json data in php to the component. But I want to define an object in javascript and send it to the vue component. Below is my .blade.php file which correctly passes the php variables.  In the script section i define a javascript object js_table_definition. That object does not want to go to the component.

```
<?php
$table_definition = (object) [
    "name" => "vendors",
    "access" => "read",
    "search_post_route" => "",
    "index_post_route" => "",
    "index_get_route" => "",
    "header_definition" => [],
    "footer_definition" => [],
    "column_definition" => [],
];
?>
@section('content')
    <div class="panel-body">
        <zzi-results-table
                v-bind:results="{{  json_encode($vendors) }}"
                v-bind:table_definition="{{  json_encode($table_definition) }}"
        >
        </zzi-results-table>
    </div>
@stop

@section('script')
    //can't get this variable to zzi-results-table
    js_table_definition = {
        "name" : "vendors",
        "access" : "read",
        "search_post_route" : "",
        "index_post_route" : "",
        "index_get_route" : "",
        "header_definition" : [],
        "footer_definition" : [],
        "column_definition" : [],
    };

@stop
```

I have tried all sorts of things without luck. I thought it would be something like

```
v-bind:table_definition="{{ js_table_definition }}"
v-bind:table_definition="@{{ js_table_definition }}"
v-bind:table_definition="js_table_definition"
js_table_definition="js_table_definition"
```

I do not want to add it to the 'data' method of the vue component as that would hardcode the global variable and make it not very reusable. I think I need to pass it over.

Here is my component js

```
    export default {
    //data: function(){
    //    return
    //    {
    //        vendors:vendors
    //    }
   // },
    props: ['results', 'table_definition'],
    mounted() {
        console.log('Hi from zzi-results-table');
        console.log(this.results);
        console.log(this.table_definition);
        var results_table = new dynamic_table(this.table_definition, this.results);

 },

}
```

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like, specifically around `v-bind:table_definition="{{  json_encode($table_definition) }}"`?

Comment: This is with the working code... dumped from php v-bind:table_definition="{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;vendors&quot;,&quot;access&quot;:&quot;read&quot;,&quot;search_post_route&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;index_post_route&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;index_get_route&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;header_definition&quot;:[],&quot;footer_definition&quot;:[],&quot;column_definition&quot;:[]}"           trying to insert the javascript variable will give a variety of results. I even tried stringify to turn it to a string

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/passing-data-from-laravel-blade-to-vuejs),  to pass Laravel variables to your views, you can use the JavaScript package: [PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer](https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer).

You can have this code, after adding this package:

```
$table_definition = (object) [
    "name" => "vendors",
    "access" => "read",
    "search_post_route" => "",
    "index_post_route" => "",
    "index_get_route" => "",
    "header_definition" => [],
    "footer_definition" => [],
    "column_definition" => [],
];

JavaScript::put([
        'table_definition' => $table_definition
 ])
```

Now `table_definition` should be available in your vue instance.

---

To pass PHP variable to vue instance, you can use approach described [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/pass-data-from-view-to-vue-instance?page=1). You should be having Vue instance started in your actual blade view. Simply within script tags and you can just do:

```
<script>
new Vue({
    data: {
        table_definition: {!! $table_definition !!}
    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: No issues creating javascript variables from php. I need the javascript variable to go to the vue component, not the instance..... i think. Should be really easy.... Unless I create a new vue instance for each page which seems wrong